# Реализация синтаксического анализатора yacc

Tags: c, lex, yacc

У меня задача:

> Разработать синтаксический анализатор для грамматического разбора
> входного потока цифровой информации с целью распознавания записей
> любых двоичных наборов, где чередуются группы с четным числом стоящих
> подряд единиц и нулей. Двоичные наборы должны передаваться
> синтаксическому анализатору строками потока стандартного ввода.
> Результаты грамматического разбора должны отображать диагностические
> сообщения потока стандартного вывода.

То есть к примеру 1100, 11110000 1100001100 и т.д.

У меня есть код:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>

int yyerror(char*);

int yylex();

int one_counter = 0;
int flag = -1;
int zero_counter = 0;

%}

%start input

%token ONE

%token ZERO

%%


input: 
{
   printf("Enter the line:\n");
}

| input line

;

line: '\n' {
   printf("Empty line\n");
}

| error '\n' {
   yyerrok;
}

| exp0 '\n' {
    printf("Correct\n");
}
;

exp0: ONE ZERO

| ONE ZERO exp0
;

%%

int yyerror(char* s){
    printf("Incorrect\n");
    return 1;
}

  int yywrap(){
      return 1;
   }

int yylex(){
    int c;
    c=getchar();

    if(c=='1'){
        if(flag==0){
            if(zero_counter>=2){
                if(zero_counter%2==0){
                   zero_counter=0;
                   return ZERO;
            
                }
                flag=1;
            }   
        }
        one_counter++;
        flag=1;
    }

    if(c=='0'){
        if(flag==1){
            if(one_counter>=2){
                if(one_counter%2==0){
                    one_counter = 0;
                    return ONE;
                }
                flag=0;
            }
        }
        zero_counter++;
        flag=0;
    }

    if (c==EOF)
    return 0;
    return c;
}

int main(){
    yyparse ();
}
```

Здесь меня выкидывает сразу же после проверки первого символа и выводит сообщение "Incorrect".
При чём прошлая решённая задача с чередованием двоичных наборов, состоящих из **01**, то есть **01010101**, была решена подобным образом. Отличались только ***yylex()*** и ***exp0*** и всё работало.

**yylex():**

```
int yylex(){
   int c;
   c=getchar();
   if (c=='1')
      return ONE;
   if (c=='0')
      return ZERO;
   if (c==EOF)
      return 0;
   return c;
}
```

**exp0:**

```
exp0: ZERO ONE

| ZERO ONE exp0
;
```

Таким же принципом попытался решить и эту, но не выходит. Искал подробную документацию в интернете на этот счёт, но всё тщетно. Как можно реализовать решение этой задачи?

Comment: Можно свести только к лексике — считывать по два символа. 11 — ONE, 00 — ZERO, все остальное — ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Можно свести только к лексике — считывать по два символа. 11 — ONE, 00 — ZERO, все остальное — ошибка. Но если очень хочется именно в синтаксис... примерно так

```
exp0: OPAIR
| ZPAIR
| OPAIR exp0
| ZPAIR exp0
;

OPAIR: ONE ONE
| ONE ONE OPAIR

ZPAIR: ZERO ZERO
| ZERO ZERO ZPAIR
```

Появится пару конфликтов shift/reduce, но работать должно :) `yylex` при этом оставляем старый, который работал просто с 01.